# Running TravisCI and Espresso Test - Android

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-espresso

this question has been raised multiple time. However, version changes and I have an old version (but newer than most people who raised this question before)

I am seeking help from the community with this as it became to much time consuming to try each version.

For my build.gradle:

```
...

android {
    flavorDimensions "none"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
              javaMaxHeapSize project.hasProperty('javaMaxHeapSize') ? project.getProperty('javaMaxHeapSize') : "4g"
    }

...

  }
    /*Espresso UI Testing
    all other required dependencies https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project */
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

}

...
```

For my travis:

```
...
"./gradlew connectedAndroidTest"
...
```

I usually get this error:

```
org.compname.secureds.ChickenStuff > changeChickenTest[test(AVD) - 5.1.1] FAILED 
    androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Chicken"
    If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{73736fc VFED..CL ......I. 24,24-456,60 #7f0900db app:id/country_spinner}
```

So my chicken test is failing, but when I run it on Android Studio. It passes. I don't know why it fails, but I assume its the version stack (build tool, platform tools, ndk tool.. etc)

Comment: Please post the code of your test. Also, is it the only test that fails?

Comment: Sure, I will do that. It is my only test.

Comment: Ok, when you post the code, I may have a better answer. That error message indicates the test does indeed run so are you able to see a video of the test run? That might help you debug. Also, can you try a very simple test that just opens the app and checks that the main layout view is displayed?